# Describing statistical outliers in specification data sheets

Tags: statistics

I have an instrument that is interrogated (say) once per second to provide a data value. After reading it for (say) 1000 seconds I have a good idea of how well it performs, with Average and Standard Deviation measurements.

The problem is this: it all looks good with accurate data etc, except there is an outlier every N readings. A customer looking at my data summary would think it is OK, but this is because the vast bulk of the data is incredibly precise and the outlier is evil, resulting in "good enough".

As a worst case, the instrument works well until one day that outlier pops up and the process it was controlling takes the refinery with it.

How do I describe the characteristics of that outlier in order to provide a more accurate data sheet? Is there some statistical tool or procedure I am missing?

Comment: You might want to read about [statistical process control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_process_control) and [control charts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_chart).  It is a major subject

Comment: A major subject I have no time to research, hence the question here. It's not hypothetical since I am designing a precision instrument of the type described above. I want to say "Occasionally you will get an outlier in all this nice data" but with some kind of precision added to the statement